# Teemo's global taunt

Tags: league-of-legends

Why do people say Teemo has a global taunt?

I'm guessing that it's because everyone focuses him on teamfights but my theory may be wrong.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, especially from someone new to League.  Please don't down-vote it. =D

Comment: Play teemo, try to global taunt. Case closed.

Comment: Everybody thinks they can chase down Teemo - until they hit a shroom...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Teemo's global taunt is a meme. Teemo is arguably the cutest and squishiest AND most annoying hero in the game. Hence, everyone wants him dead, hence, 'Global Taunt'.

Teemo has in actuality, no taunt of any kind.

Comment: My other theory was that he would laugh while invisible to annoy the enemy team, but that was not global :P

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: quite true but he can still affect the fight while dead